# Parsing formdata from React using Serverless and API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, serverless-framework

I'm trying to upload a file and send data from a React frontend to a S3 bucket using an API Gateway/ Lambda function setup using the Serverless framework and I've been struggling with it for the last couple of days.

From the frontend I am using axios and creating a formdata to send a post request to the API like the following:

```js
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('imageFile', selectedImage);
    formData.append('itemId', clubIdRef.current.value);
    formData.append('itemDescription', itemDescRef.current.value);

    axios.post(
                baesURL+"/item/create", formData,
                    {headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }}
                
                
            ).then((response) => {
                console.log("response" + response)
                console.log("response.data" + response.data)
            })
```

Appending string attributes to the formdata feels off but the only way I could find to send data and an image at the same time was like the above.

Then to receive this data in the backend I've been using `lambda-multipart-parser` like the following:

```js
const createItem = async (event) => {

  const result = await multipartParser.parse(event);
  const imageFile = result.imageFile;
  const itemDescription = result.itemDescription;
```

where the result console logs as:

```json
{
  files: [],
  imageFile: '[object File]',
  itemId: '12',
  itemDescription: "Description"
}
```

I can then store the imageFile successfully in S3 and generate the URL. Next, I create an `Item` object with the S3 url and id and description to store in dynamoDB. Everything works fine but when I open the S3 url the file is corrupted and just opens as a grey box instead of the actual image I uploaded.

This is how I am uploading the file using the s3 sdk

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: `images/${directoryPath}/${id}.png`,
      Body: imageFile,
      ContentType: "image/png",
      ACL : "public-read"
    }
    
uploadResult = await s3.putObject(params).promise();
```

These are the things I've tried but still don't have any success uploading the correct image to my S3 bucket:

1. Looking and changing the [BinaryMediaType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397818/upload-image-from-form-data-to-s3-using-a-lambda) of the API gateway but I can't find the settings under the API...
2. Tried using [aws-lambda-multipart-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-multipart-parser) but still wasn't able to add multipart/form-data binary media type and parse the full form data correctly

I know that I could first try to send a request directly from React to S3 to upload the image using `aws-sdk` in react to get a preSignedURL and attach that URL and make a POST request to my API Gateway simply parse the `event.body` without having to use a multipart form parser, but I want to avoid sending multiple requests if needed and handle everything in the backend.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It is quite hard to understand where is the problem with given context.
We have no idea which image format you are uploading, no idea how you store this image to S3.
My answer will try to cover these missing informations as it is a common mistake on S3 uploads.

S3 files are stored and returned with given ContentType.
You might check your S3 file's ContentType on AWS console.

> Console > S3 > Select object (image) > Metadata > ContentType

I will suppose that image format is PNG and image data is correct and might be posted to S3 as is (from `result`).

**S3Service.ts**

```js
import AWS, {S3} from "aws-sdk";
import {PutObjectRequest} from "aws-sdk/clients/s3";
import {PutObjectResponse} from "aws-sdk/clients/mediastoredata";

AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-3' });
const s3: S3 = new AWS.S3();

export class S3Service {
    public static async putImage(key: string, data: string, contentType: string): Promise<PutObjectResponse> {
        const s3Params: PutObjectRequest = {
            Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
            Key: key,
            Body: data,
            ContentType: contentType // <== I draw your attention here
        }
        return await s3.putObject(s3Params).promise()
    }
}
```

**index.ts**

```js
import { S3Service } from "service/aws/s3-service";

await S3Service.putImage(result.itemId + ".png", result.imageFile, "image/png");
```

A common mistake, which I assume might be the cause of your problem, is to forget content-type resulting in incorrect download format.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just added a section of how I use the aws S3 sdk to upload the object. I do specify the content type and send over a png file. But I am still get a small grey blob when I open the public url

Comment: @ph-quiett Image file (data) must be sent as blob. I recommend using fetch + blob like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob)

Comment: why is that the case? I see that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168847/12534379), sending the image as a form data is enough. And blob seems like it's only used on the response and not the request to the backend

Comment: How do you read "imageFile" from your backend ? Aren't you considering it as a string ?
Blob does stand for Binary Large OBject, I recommend to use this format as you will control how data is sent and how it is processed by your backend, moreover you will not have any side effect due to sending "text" through API.